# pscp network error: connection timed out

Tags: windows, file-transfer, remote-server, pscp

*NOTE* I am running on windows 10, not linux.

pscp.exe has been downloaded and run in my \Users\Taylor folder.  I turned off my firewall just in case that could be interfering. I am trying to download files to my local windows from a remote linux environment using the following input to command prompt:

```
pscp user@quanah.hpcc.ttu.edu:/home/user/*.ctl \Downloads
```

I also varied the local name as such:

```
pscp user@quanah.hpcc.ttu.edu:/home/user/*.ctl C:\Users\Taylor\Downloads
```

This has worked perfectly in the past (~ one week ago), but now I get the error: "Fatal: Network error: Connection timed out" - I know the server (quanah.hpcc.ttu.edu) is connected and fine because I can ssh to it via PuTTY.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure that once I get the dos shell going, I navigate to where pscp.exe is located and run your command from there, i.e.:

C:\Users\Taylor>pscp ...

I'd also go to the source directory on quanah.hpcc.ttu.edu, in your case, '/home/user/' and do 'pwd' to confirm full path

I'd also set my target directory to be where pscp.exe is located i.e. C:\Users\Taylor because I've had success with that; and not because that is the only way.